# Variables in PHP String

Tags: php, python, email

So I'm trying to execute a python function from PHP, but for some reason it doesn't work when I want to add a variable.

It works fine when I do it from the shell like this:

```
python -c 'import smtp; smtp.email("Email Body")'
```

But when I run it from PHP it won't work if I add the variable:

```
exec("python -c 'import smtp; smtp.email({$email})'");
```

I'm certain the python is right, but why won't this work? Every post I see   shows variables inserted like this.

Comment: So if you hardcode the $email value it works? If you print the $email value do you get what you expected?

Comment: Try `echo "python -c 'import smtp; smtp.email({$email})'"` and see if that's identical to your hardcoded version. Hint: it's not.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you just forgot to use \" for email body.

```
exec("python -c 'import smtp; smtp.email(\"$email\")'");
```